# Vertical-align UL LI elements for multi-line text

Tags: html, css

I have a ul list which has a few single and some multi-line li text..
Now for the multi-line text, the 2nd line of text starts at a different indentation than the 1st line of text.

I want a very basic approach to fix this issue which should be cross-browser compatible.

Just to add, I want some space between the ul and a neighboring image (so kind of margin)

My HTML and CSS;

```
<div class="fl">
    <div class="resDtp2"><img src="images/book1.gif"></div>
    <ul class="resDtp2 txtSmall">
        <li class="resDtpPad"><span>Some text Some text Some text</span></li>
        <li class="resDtpPad"><span>Some text</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>


div.resDtp1{float:none}
div.resDtp2{float:left}
ul li.resDtpPad{text-align: left;}
```

Comment: Can you show us your current CSS/HTML, or put it in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)? `<li>` elements, by default, will have a disc and all text pushed to the right of that disc, no matter how many lines you have.

Comment: an example is better to understand what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the li's a padding-left, that should do it

Comment: Well..I did try that and it creates the diff indentation issue which i mentioned..

Comment: Your li's are display:block, yes? And fixed width? Show your HTML CSS as an example. Use jsfiddle.com